# Cannot find module in node_modules folder (but file exist)

Tags: laravel, typescript, vue.js

When i run `yarn run watch` (inside my laravel project root) it compiles with no errors. However if i edit a file afterwards it show an error in the terminal for every single `.ts` file in my `resources` folder. Typescript in `.vue` files has no issues. Also note that every change i make seems to be compiled as well, so in other words, it works... but the error messages stay in the console.

The error i am getting for each `.ts` file is:

```
TS2307: Cannot find module '!../../../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/runtime/componentNormalizer.js' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

This file does exist inside my `node_module` folder.

I have googled it an the only thing i found remotely close to my problem is this link:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/634

But none of the suggested solution/workarounds there work for me.

This is my tsconfig

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
    },
    "include": [
        "resources/js/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "vendor",
    ]
}
```

I suspect it is either a configuration issue or a version problem in `ts-loader` or `vue-loader`.

```
"ts-loader": "^8.2.0",
"typescript": "^4.3.2"
"vue-loader": "^15.7.0",
```

webpack config:

```
module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    loader: "ts-loader",
                    options: {appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]},
                    exclude: /node_modules/
                },
            ]
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx", ".vue", ".ts", ".tsx"]
        }
```

Keep in mind i have to use `8.2.` in order for laravel-mix to be able to work with it. Also i use `vue-class-components` and `vue-property-decator`

Comment: Update your `package.json` file 
then run this 
npm update laravel-mix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the exact same issue in several projects, the only difference being that I'm using Symfony's webpack-encore with slightly different tsconfig.json, but I guess the underlying problem might be the same.

In my case I was using an `app.js` file as the entry-file. Changing this to `app.ts` resolved this issue. I have no clue why this matters (maybe anyone can elaborate).

Comment: Thank you so much, renaming the resources app file from `app.js` to `app.ts` made the errors dissapear.

Comment: Wow ! I've the exact same error and renaming the entry file from `.js` to `.ts` resolve the issue ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your webpack config if you didn't.

https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#typescript

```js
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    // Add `.ts` as a resolvable extension.
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ... other rules omitted
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: { appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/] }
      }
    ]
  },
  // ... plugin omitted
}
```

if it does not work
try this

change your typescript version to   "typescript": "~3.9.3",

Comment: i already had this webpack config and as an addition node_modules folder is excluded. change the typescript version did nothing for me.

Comment: "allowSyntheticDefaultImports" : true  
in your ts-config

Comment: not working, remember it compiles fine the first time, but not after editing file while watcher running

Comment: ok I think i got it :).
it's about your typescript config ..
your include is not correct I think 
try that in your ts-config 
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]

Comment: this is a laravel project as stated in the question. in laravel projects the js source root is resources/assets/js, also this is not the issue. everything compiles, and works even despite all the errors. but i have just no clue what is causing these errors to appear.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a sanity check answer, I do not know much about laravel, apologies. But...

1. If the 'file' exists insofar as you can find it in node_modules
2. if there is nothing in the tsconfig or anywhere else to rule out this resolution behavior
3. if that [file](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/blob/v15.7.0/lib/runtime/componentNormalizer.js) there in that commit does indeed exist and export a function (and has for a long time at that)
4. if you are indeed using yarn

One thing I would *definitely* rule out in all this is:  [yarn links](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/link/), and [yarn workspaces](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/).  These could be active for some unknown reason (probably not the latter, which would be pretty obvious of you) and causing this weirdness.

One quick thing to rule the former (stray link) out:

```sh
rm <YARN_CONFIG_DIR>/link/*
```

typically

```sh
rm ~/.config/yarn/link/*
```